# is there a way to get individual components of heroku toolbelt?

Tags: git, heroku, foreman

Is there a way to download and install heroku toolbelt components individually, or at least without the bundled git? Heroku Toolbelt comes with git bundled in. Last time I downloaded it and installed it, it overwrote my existing git installation. Heroku Toolbelt bundles an older version of git and I require at least 1.7.10. Is there a way to just install heroku and foreman? This seems a little weird that there isn't such an option considering most heroku users would be developer likely to have git already.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just Foreman, Git, and the Heroku CLI client.

[image: Customize Heroku Toolbelt Install Screen]

If you already have Git and Foreman, you can just install the CLI from the command line,

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
```

The Windows installer offers the same options.

Answer (score 6):

I would use mxcl's homebrew to install the heroku-toolbelt.

Answer (score 0):

On OS X you select which components to install:  At the “installation type” stage there's a “customise” button at the bottom of the window that lets you pick which component(s) you want.

(I haven't used the Linux or Windows installers, so I don't know if they provide the same customisation options.)